# ffplay - how to get only single channel audio from video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, waveform

For a video file, how can I only get the showwave filter instead of both showwave n spectrum.

ffplay -f lavfi 'amovie=abc.mp4,asplit=3[out1][a][b]; [a]showwaves=s=640x240[waves]; [b]showspectrum=s=640x240[spectrum]; [waves][spectrum] vstack[out0]'

And this shows the video as audio waveform but i get 2 identical waveform (most prob left/right)
ffplay - showmode 1 abc.mp4

Comment: showwaves and spectrum are filters, not channels. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry abt that. Rephrase my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi 'amovie=abc.mp4,asplit=2[out1][waves];[waves]pan=1c|c0=c0,showwaves=s=640x240[out0]'
```

The `pan` filter here keeps only the first channel, which is, likely, the Left channel. Change `c0=c0` to `c0=c1` to keep the Right only.

Comment: awesome works ! Love stackoverflow ! hahah
Also found this in case anyone else is unsure:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Mixing-examples

Comment: Sorry is it possible to get the identical Single audio channel using the showmode?
In showmode i get the scrubbing back n forth feature which is absent in the above solution

ffplay -showmode 1 abc.mp4